# Is there a formal enumeration of the ways that components can be coupled / depend on eachother?

Tags: research, dependencies, formal-methods

Say you have

```
class A {
}

class B {
}
```

One type dependency is "method parameter":

```
class A {
}

class B {
  public void M(A a) {
  }
}
```

Another is "method returns":

```
class A {
}

class B {
  public A M() {
  }
}
```

Then C, an adapter from A to B, could be identified by a class that exhibits both of the above dependency characteristics:

```
class C {
  public B M(A a) {
  }
}
```

I just seems like something that could be approached with some formal methods and I'd be interested to read about them if they are out there?

Comment: There are various kinds of type systems which may have other forms of relationships not possible in the java/C# style type system. You didn't mention generic constraint as a type dependency, and the language you refer to doesn't have parametric polymorphism which opens up more types of relationships. There may be a valid enumeration as you're referring to that is the set of possible type relationships in language X or Y, but the set of possible relationships in the set of type systems/languages which includes all of them is likely never been enumerated outside of type theorists

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory

Comment: another approach which may actually have documentation out there would be to recognize a type as a set, and then try and identify if there can be homomorphic/isomorphic/endomorphic/monomorphic etc relationships between the types given the type system available.